# How Can I do performance testing using Rest Assured

Tags: rest, performance-testing, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am using rest assured to automate my project. In the same project, I want to do performance testing in the API. I want to know how can I achieve this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have existing set of tests and want to run them in multithreaded manner the options are in:

- use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to run them in parallel
- "wrap" them into functions with [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) annotations
- use a load testing tool capable of running [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/) tests (or whatever is your [xUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit) framework) like [JUnit Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) of [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

However the above approaches will only allow you to kick off your tests in parallel and you won't be able to collect a lot of metrics like:

- number of active threads
- number of hits per seconds
- response time
- HTTP-protocol-based metrics like [response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), connect time, latency

so it makes sense considering converting your restassured tests into "real" tests driven by the "normal" load testing tool, the majority of load testing tools provide record-and-replay capability by exposing a [HTTP Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) so if you [run your restassured tests via this proxy](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.4/io/restassured/RestAssured.html#proxy-java.lang.String-int-)  the load testing tool will capture them and convert them into corresponding HTTP requests.

Comment: I record my rest-assured API request in JMeter it is work.

Comment: can I know other performance testing tool can be integrated to rest assured code??